# Error while running linux command in Python using subprocess

Tags: linux, python-3.x, subprocess, os.system

The goal here is to get a key or p/w from a website.

In Python, I have tried both os.system() and subprocess.call([]) to run following linux command but both method ends up with error.

```
os.system("curl -s http://example.com | grep ' "Key" : * ' | cut -f1 -d " " | cut -b5- | rev | cut -b9- | rev")
```

In linux following is being used and that works fine.

```
PW = 'curl -s http://example.com | grep ' "Key" : * ' | cut -f1 -d " " | cut -b5- | rev | cut -b8- | rev'
```

The error I see is SyntaxError: invalid syntax and it points at the "key" part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to escape your double quotes. Try:

```
os.system("curl -s http://example.com | grep ' \"Key\" : * ' | cut -f1 -d \" \" | cut -b5- | rev | cut -b9- | rev")
```

Comment: You are right, that was the problem. Code runs correctly now, but how do I assign output of this code to a new variable ? I mean I tried doing pass = os.system(....) but it just prints the key but when I check the variable it returns 0